# Sum of chosen primes is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Fix a positive integer $k\geq 2$. Can we always find infinitely many primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ such that the sum of any $k$ of them is composite?

If $k$ is even, it is clear that we can. We only need to not choose $2$, so that all the chosen primes are odd, and the sum of any $k$ of them is even, hence composite. But what about if $k$ is odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the primes so that they are all congruent to $1$ modulo $k$.  That we can find infinitely many is a consequence of [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on primes in arithmetic progressions.